# How do I specify Thirty360::European day counter in RQuantLib

Tags: r, quantlib

I am taking liberty to ask the following question in quantLib forum though this question is about RQuantLib

I am trying to use RQuantLib to calculate clean price of a fixed coupon bond using a Nelson-Siegel ZCYC. I need to use 30/360 European daycounter to calculate fraction of year between the settlement date and coupon payment schedule. I don't see any where what will be the enumerated value for the above dayCounter?

Please help.